# Amadeus booking/flight-orders POST API returns Error during the creation of the FOP, code : 25779

Tags: amadeus

I am developing amadeus booking system. my booking/flight-orders POST api was working fine until 19th July 2023. Since then without any code change, i've started to get this error

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 500,
      "code": 141,
      "title": "SYSTEM ERROR HAS OCCURRED",
      "detail": "Error during the creation of the FOP, code : 25779"
    }
  ]
}
```

The request payload is:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "type": "flight-order",
    "flightOffers": [
      {
        "type": "flight-offer",
        "id": "13",
        "source": "GDS",
        "instantTicketingRequired": false,
        "nonHomogeneous": false,
        "oneWay": false,
        "lastTicketingDate": "2023-07-22",
        "lastTicketingDateTime": "2023-07-22",
        "numberOfBookableSeats": 9,
        "itineraries": [
          {
            "duration": "PT18H15M",
            "segments": [
              {
                "departure": {
                  "iataCode": "MEL",
                  "terminal": "2",
                  "at": "2023-07-24T21:15:00"
                },
                "arrival": {
                  "iataCode": "DXB",
                  "terminal": "3",
                  "at": "2023-07-25T05:15:00"
                },
                "carrierCode": "EK",
                "number": "407",
                "aircraft": { "code": "388" },
                "operating": { "carrierCode": "EK" },
                "duration": "PT14H",
                "id": "30",
                "numberOfStops": 0,
                "blacklistedInEU": false
              },
              {
                "departure": {
                  "iataCode": "DXB",
                  "terminal": "2",
                  "at": "2023-07-25T07:20:00"
                },
                "arrival": {
                  "iataCode": "KHI",
                  "terminal": "M",
                  "at": "2023-07-25T10:30:00"
                },
                "carrierCode": "EK",
                "number": "2110",
                "aircraft": { "code": "7M8" },
                "operating": { "carrierCode": "FZ" },
                "duration": "PT2H10M",
                "id": "31",
                "numberOfStops": 0,
                "blacklistedInEU": false
              }
            ]
          }
        ],
        "price": {
          "currency": "USD",
          "total": "1194.20",
          "base": "1121.00",
          "fees": [
            { "amount": "0.00", "type": "SUPPLIER" },
            { "amount": "0.00", "type": "TICKETING" }
          ],
          "grandTotal": "1194.20"
        },
        "pricingOptions": {
          "fareType": ["PUBLISHED"],
          "includedCheckedBagsOnly": true
        },
        "validatingAirlineCodes": ["EK"],
        "travelerPricings": [
          {
            "travelerId": "1",
            "fareOption": "STANDARD",
            "travelerType": "ADULT",
            "price": {
              "currency": "USD",
              "total": "1194.20",
              "base": "1121.00"
            },
            "fareDetailsBySegment": [
              {
                "segmentId": "30",
                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                "fareBasis": "KLSOSAU1",
                "brandedFare": "ECOFLEX",
                "class": "K",
                "includedCheckedBags": { "weight": 30, "weightUnit": "KG" }
              },
              {
                "segmentId": "31",
                "cabin": "ECONOMY",
                "fareBasis": "KLSOSAU1",
                "brandedFare": "ECOFLEX",
                "class": "K",
                "includedCheckedBags": { "weight": 30, "weightUnit": "KG" }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "travelers": [
      {
        "documents": [],
        "id": "1",
        "dateOfBirth": "1985-10-20",
        "contact": {
          "phones": [
            {
              "countryCallingCode": "92",
              "deviceType": "MOBILE",
              "number": 1234567890
            }
          ],
          "emailAddress": "check@gmail.com"
        },
        "gender": "MALE",
        "ticketingAgreement": "CONFIRM",
        "name": { "firstName": "Testing", "lastName": "One" }
      }
    ],
    "formOfPayments": [
      {
        "creditCard": {
          "brand": "VISA",
          "holder": "Testing One",
          "number": 4012999999999999,
          "expiryDate": "2025-12",
          "securityCode": 123,
          "flightOfferIds": ["13"]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Error 500 typically means the error was internal to the service you're communicating with.  Absent any available documentation regarding error code 141, you'll likely need to communicate with the provider's support.

Comment: I've tried messaging Amadeus but they arent responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more i know about the way this business operated, i have found the answer. We need to remove the FormOfPayment information object before posting it to Amadeus.